# Se pierde el routing al cargar el controlador

Tags: php, .htaccess, mvc

estoy realizando pruebas con MVC en PHP, y estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de enrutar hacia otro controlador, por defecto hay un controlador y método (acción) asignados en caso de no encontrar lo recibido.

#### El problema está a la hora de incluir el controlador en el routing, dice que no encuentra la clase en el directorio actual, la ruta la paso absoluta.

Accedo de esta forma para que se produzca el error `dominio/articles`

La única forma que me funciona es con `dominio/home/algun_metodo`

> El **.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z_-]+)/?$ index.php?controller=articles&action=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]*)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=index [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]*)/?([a-z_-]*)/?$ index.php?controller=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

> El **index.php** en la raíz del proyecto

```
// ONLY DEBUG

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// DEPENDENCIAS (FUNCIONAN PERFECTAMENTE)

require_once '_core_/_config.php';
require_once '_core_/_utils.php';
require_once '_core_/_model.php';
require_once '_core_/_controller.php';

// VISTA GENÉRICA (ESTE LLAMA AL ROUTING)

require_once '_core_/_view.php';
```

> El **_view.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- metas -->
    <!-- links -->
</head
<body>
    <?php require_once('_routes.php');?>
    <!-- scripts -->
</body>
</html>
```

> El **_route.php** *aquí es dónde se produce el fatal error*

```
function _loadController($controller)
{
    $controller_path = PATH_CONTROLLERS.PREFIX_CONTROLLER.$controller.'.php';
    if (!file_exists($controller_path)) {
        $controller_path = PATH_CONTROLLERS.PREFIX_CONTROLLER.DEFAULT_CONTROLLER.'.php';
    }
    require_once $controller_path;
    die('El require_once para cargar el controlador no funciona: 
        Fatal Error - Class not found en este fichero (está en este: /src/controllers/cnt_articles.php)
        pero la ruta es absoluta, que falla?');
    $controller_name = ucfirst(PREFIX_CONTROLLER).$controller;
    return new $controller_name;
}
$controller = _loadController(isset($_GET['controller']) && 
                                !empty($_GET['controller']) 
                                    ? $_GET['controller'] : DEFAULT_CONTROLLER);
$method = isset($_GET['action']) && 
            !empty($_GET['action']) && 
                method_exists($controller, $_GET['action']) 
                    ? $_GET['action'] : DEFAULT_METHOD;
$controller->{$method}();
```

> Algunas constantes de **_config.php**

```
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define("PATH_MODELS",ROOT_PATH."/src/models/");
define("PATH_VIEWS",ROOT_PATH."/src/views/");
define("PATH_CONTROLLERS",ROOT_PATH."/src/controllers/");
define("PREFIX_MODEL","mdl_");
define("PREFIX_VIEW","vw_");
define("PREFIX_CONTROLLER","cnt_");
define("SUFIX_HELPER","_helper");
```

Comment: Cual es el valor de DEFAULT_CONTROLLER al momento de ejecutar? No lo veo en la lista de constantes. Haz un `echo $controller_path ` justo antes del `require_once`.

Comment: Es de 'home' nunca llega bien , porqué?

Comment: Esta regla: `RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z_-]+)/?$ index.php?controller=articles&action=$1 [L]` no se va a ejecutar si la URI es `dominio/articles`.  La regex esta emparejando `artices/[algo]`.

Answer (score 0):

Si entiendo bien, quieres que esta regla:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/([a-z_-]+)/?$ index.php?controller=articles&action=$1 [L]
```

se ejecute en los casos siguentes: `dominio/articles`, `dominio/articles/`, `dominio/articles/action`, `dominio/articles/action/`

Para hacerlo hay que modificar la regex para que tome en cuenta los casos cuando hay o no hay `/`, cuando hay o no hay `action`, y cuando hay o no hay `/` al final. Por ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/?([a-z_-]+)?/?$ index.php?controller=articles&action=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

te da (URI --> resultado):

```
dominio/articles   -->  index.php?controller=articles&action=
dominio/articles/  -->  index.php?controller=articles&action=
dominio/articles/act -->  index.php?controller=articles&action=act
dominio/articles/act/ -->  index.php?controller=articles&action=act
```

Comment: El problema persiste Vrac: 

Fatal error: Class 'Cnt_articles' not found in /Users/miuser/foo_mvc/_core_/_routes.php on line 13

Comment: Sugiero que saques todo de tu index.php menos el require_once y la creacion del objeto Cnt_articles para minimizar las posibilidades. Pon el path directamente, sin variables, en el require_once. De ahi vas agregrando codigo hasta que encuentres el problema.

Comment: Nada, sigo en las mismas una vez revierto los pasos y se hace 'dinámico'.